# IBM Watson Assistant - Return after digression without responding again

Tags: watson-conversation, watson-assistant

I'm wondering if I can use a digression with a return to the previous flow, without having the bot responding again.

For the details, I'm using digressions so the user can jump from a child node to a root node (for example "`wait`"). The problem is that the conversation looks like this :

---

- **Hello, I'm Watson.**
- How are you ?
- **Fine and you ?**
- Wait a second... `// Digression to node 'wait'`
- **I'll hold on.** `// Digression back to previous node`
- **Fine and you ?** `// I would like this not to be said again.`

---

Any way of doing so without catching the "digression event" in back-end and manually delete the second "**Fine and you ?**" ?

Answer (score 0):

Put `<? clearDialogStack() ?>` and digression will be cleared.